# boost::asio::io_context метод stopped неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Есть следующий код

```
boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> ioContext = nullptr;
ioContext = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::io_context>();
...
if (ioContext->stopped())
{...}
```

Во время сборки, получаю ошибку линковщика:

```
1>DownloadDirect.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall boost::asio::io_context::stopped(void)const " (?stopped@io_context@asio@boost@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall DownloadDirect::downloadFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?downloadFile@DownloadDirect@@IAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
```

Если убираю ioContext->stopped(), то ошибка пропадает, при этом в коде используется множество других методов от ioContext и с ними такой проблемы нет

Используется boost 1.68.0 и Visual Studio 2017

boost собирал таким образом:

```
.\b2 toolset=msvc address-model=32 -j8 threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static variant=debug runtime-debugging=on --build-type=complete
```

После указал все необходимые пути в настройках проекта и указал в настройках препроцессора BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION

В какую сторону еще можно копать?